# Prove $2^n > n^2 + n + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I did this but I'm pretty sure it's wrong

$P(5) $ is true
Assume $P(k)$ is true
for some $k \ge 5$, ie. $2^k > k^2 + k + 1$

$$2^{k+1} = (k + 1)^2 + (k + 1) + 1$$
$$2^{k+1} = k^2 + 3k + 3$$

Then:

$$2^{k+1} > (k^2 + k + 1) \cdot 2 > k^2 + 3k + 3$$

$$2^{k+1} > k^2 > k + 1$$

From the onset we know that:

$$2^{k+1} > 2^k > k^2 + k + 1$$

Therefore:

$$2^{k+1} > 2^k$$ (which is true)

Therefore, by the PMI, $P(k)$ is true for all $k \ge 5$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be much better if you use MathJax instead of posting a link, you can learn the basics about it here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you don't bother to type your question using MathJax your questions will be poorly received in this site. If you don't show some effort writing your questions they will probably be closed.

Comment: ohh got it let me edit it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You proof is correct to the point where you need to prove that $2(k^2+k+1)>{(k+1)}^2+k+1+1$, or that $k^2-k-1>0$. For this last part you either redo the induction or use $k^2>2k$, which is true for k>2.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You started well but the end of your proof is not right and it is unclear when you write 2 inequalities.

We want to prove $2^{k+1}>(k+1)^2+(k+1)+1$ knowing already that $2^k>k^2+k+1$.

$2^{k+1}=2\times2^k>2\times(k^2+k+1)=2k^2+2k+2$ but we wanted to prove $2^{k+1}>(k+1)^2+(k+1)+1=k^2+3k+3$ so it is enough to prove that $2k^2+2k+2>k^2+3k+3$.

Which is the same as $k^2>k+1\iff k(k-1)-1>0$ which is always true for any $k\geq5$.

Then $2^{k+1}>2\times(k^2+k+1)>(k+1)^2+(k+1)+1$ and so the proof is done.

Comment: ohhh! I get it thank you!